Edge Modes and SPT Order
I am trying to understand the notion of edge modes in the context of symmetry protected topological order (SPTO) and its relation (if there is any) with the virtual quantum register that sits at the virtual bond of the MPS representation of the  SPTO quantum state.
For concreteness, let us take the example of the 1D cluster Hamiltonian with open boundary conditions
$\displaystyle H_c= -\sum_{i=2}^{N-1}Z_{i-1}X_{i}Z_{i+1}$ which has a fourfold degeneracy.
I have seen the following statements made in this context but am not sure what they precisely mean. Clarifying them further would significantly improve my comprehension.

The model has a ground state with
a symmetric bulk, while the action of the symmetry
on the edges is said to fractionalize.
In the non-trivial
SPT phase, it gives rise to spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ degrees of freedom
localized on the edges of the chain and independent of the dynamics.

On a related matter, the idea of "edge modes" (I am not sure what that term exactly means) seem to be inextricably linked to the existence of degeneracy. Does that mean if one added the terms like $X_1Z_2$ and $Z_{N-1}X_N$ and removed the degeneracy of the ground state, the "edge modes" would be lost too? If so, does the 1D cluster state itself have no edge modes associated with it?
Finally, is there any relation between edge modes, projective representations and MPS virtual registers since they all seem to be used to encode and process quantum information in SPT phases?
P.S. I apologize for not being more succinct in my question. However, this is the best I could manage, as I frequently encounter these related concepts but lack a comprehensive understanding of their interrelationship.

Your points 1. and 2. are both related to 'fractionalization' of symmetry quantum numbers on the boundary of SPT phases. The way I understand this, which applies to 1d or higher dimensional SPT phases is as follows: ask yourself what a fraction of something means. Eg: what is the difference between half a banana and, say a small banana. One important feature is that if you see half a banana, you know there is another half somewhere in the universe. The same can be said about fractional symmetry quantum numbers. If you have a system made up of spin-1 particles and find, as you do in the AKLT chain, a boundary transforming as spin 1/2, you know that there should be another spin 1/2 somewhere else (the other boundary). The notion of projective representations, which classify 1d bosonic SPT phases, formalizes the notion of fractionalization even when we do not have the luxury of labeling charges by actual integers and fractions. For higher dimensions, the representation of symmetry on a local part of the boundary would appear to be `incomplete' without considering the whole boundary in more sphisticated ways. I recommend this excellent paper by Else and Nayak to understand this.
Regarding your question about the cluster state Hamiltonian: you are disregarding the important aspect of symmetry. Recall that edge states of SPT phases are robust against perturbations that preserve symmetry.  The cluster state Hamiltonian has many symmetries but the SPT-ness is protected by only a few. Let me list two well-known ones: (1) $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry generated by operators $\prod_{even~j} X_j$ and $\prod_{odd~j} X_j$ or (2) Time reversal, generated by $\prod_{j}X_j~\mathcal{K}$ where $\mathcal{K}$ is complex conjugation. The unitary $\mathbb{Z]}_2$ symmetry of the Hamiltonian, generated by $\prod_j X_j$ for example does not protected any SPT phase. You can check that the operators that lift your degeneracy do not commute with either of the two SPT protecting symmetries.
Finally, regarding the terminology of edge 'modes', I think this is borrowed from the study of non-interacting systems where many-body states are enumerated by second quantization where you occupy or not occupy first-quantized modes. For interacting systems, I think the terminology that is less confusing are edge states which ought to be used for interacting systems such as the Cluster state.
All this can be understood using the language of MPS in 1D as explained nicely in these papers by Chen et al, Schuch et al and Fidkowski, Kitaev.
